# SQL Can I Declare a variables data type based on another variable

Tags: sql, variables, case, sqldatatypes

I'm trying to figure out some elegant code to declare a variable type dynamically. For Example

```
Declare @DateType INT = 2
--When DateType = 2 Then Fiscal Week Else Specific Date
CASE WHEN @DateType = 2 THEN DECLARE @BeginDate INT ELSE DECLARE @BeginDate DATE
```

Or something like this

```
IF @DateType <> 2
BEGIN
DECLARE @DateRangeStart  DATE
DECLARE @DateRangeEnd    DATE
END
IF @DateType = 2
BEGIN
DECLARE @DateRangeStart  INT
DECLARE @DateRangeEnd    INT
END
```

So something like what those are trying to do but works. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why would you want something like this?

Comment: So my end users in SSRS could choose to enter a custom date range or choose fiscal weeks, months, ect for the report.

Comment: I would use `sql_variant` and cast accordingly @datetype. But I need to see code usage to evaluate furder implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not real answer, too much for a comment

```
DECLARE @DateType int

DECLARE @DateRangeStart  sql_variant

SET @DateRangeStart=8

IF @DateType <> 2
BEGIN
select convert(int,@DateRangeStart)
END
IF @DateType = 2
BEGIN
select convert(date,@DateRangeStart)
END
```